# What could cause my application compatibility issues between x64 and x86 architectures?

Tags: visual-c++, sfml, 32bit-64bit

I'm working on a VC++ app, and my job is to correct some bugs in it, the code was mainly written by a student last year.
It is a graphical application that uses both SFML and TGUI.

**It targets 32bits architectures** but actually its **only working well on x64** computers.

On a x64 , absolutly everything works perfectly , but on a 32-bits systems , the text displayed using sf:Text and sf:Font just prints black blocks after the first call to the function that sets sf:Text's string.

**I know that code targeting 32bits systems should work fine on x64 , and that's why I am lost. I checked which system architecture I am targeting.**

I am using compatibles , 32bits , last updated SFML and TGUi libraries.
I checked a billion times if I got the right dlls, include and lib paths . The linker > start property got all .lib that both sfml and tgui relies on.

I know that the Font is loaded, but I know that it doesn't stay set on the Text even if the variable containing the font isn't destroyed and that I have set the font on the text earlier.

This is how the font is loaded and associated with the text :

MainWindow.cpp :

```
Font& MainWindow::m_fontDisplayer = m_data.getFont_1();


//init displayer
m_data.getDisplayer().setFont(m_fontDisplayer);
m_data.setDisplayer("");
m_data.getDisplayer().setCharacterSize(54);
m_data.getDisplayer().setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 255));
```

DataManager(m_data):

```
Font DataManager::m_font_1 = Font();
if (!m_font_1.loadFromFile("Ressources/font_1.ttf"))
{
    printf("\nCould not find font_1.ttf font.");
}

void DataManager::setDisplayer(std::string s) {
if (m_displayer.getFont() == NULL) {
    //m_displayer.setFont(m_font_1);
}
m_displayer.setString(s);
m_displayer.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(320 - m_displayer.getGlobalBounds().width,82));}
```

This function is the one that maked me say that the font isn't set to the Text after some time.(m_displayer is sf::Text)Because I have set a stop point at the commented line and that it is accessed even if setting the font is the first thing that i do. Actually , that "if" statement was only to check the stop point, It doesn't fix the problem (makes my app crash on 32bit), and it would be too long because sf:Font operations are really heavy.

**What could possibly cause that compatibility issue between the two architectures?** 
To add to what i said , I'm sure that the only difference between the systems im testing on is the architecture and not windows version. I tried on multiple computers, and again , **the problems only appaers on 32-bit computers.**

Thanks to anyone that could explain and help me understand the problem.

**EDIT** : I cleared the text about Tgui issues as i solved them.

Comment: The "black blocks" and "after some time" scenario is typically explained by a handle leak.  Pretty common bug when the app hasn't been tested long enough, it might take a while before stuff start to fall over.  Use Task Manager, Processes tab and add the GDI Objects counter.  Also add Handles and USER Objects, just in case.  Function calls starts failing when the count approach 10000.  A code review that ensures function failure doesn't go unnoticed is warranted as well.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for your answer mate.

Comment: @hans Actually I don't think a handle leak is the cause because no malloc , realloc are used here. Is there other cases in C++ where I must free memory ? Also , windows 10 doesn't allow me to count gdi objecs via the task manager. I will give a try to handlers i think , but i'm new to c++ and I don't know about USER objects. I can't find stuff about that , do you have a good link that teach me ? To add to what you said , my function fails from the second time it is called. (stack wouldn't let me edit)